# Update Cognito User Pool/AWS Resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework, aws-userpools

I am using serverless framework to deploy AWS resources (User Pool, Identity Pool, Dynamo Tables). I know you're not allowed to make changes to a User Pool once it is already created (and similarly Dynamo indexes). I was wondering what the best practice is to update these types of resources without deleting users/data? Thankfully serverless caught the problem upon deploying

> Updates are not allowed for property - UserPoolName

But I have heard of people dropping users by accidentally updating User Pools.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Make sure you check the docs to see which attributes you are and are not allowed to change for an existing pool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this well documented AWS Blog on how to change attributes of Amazon Cognito user pool after creation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cognito-change-user-pool-attributes/

In Summary: You have to re-create a new user pool with new attributes that you want, and then use a lambda function to migrate users. Sadly, this seems to be the only way.

Comment: How to handle that kind of replacement with CloudFormation?